# Yii ActiveRecord and Console Commands not working

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, console, command

I have a problem with Yii + CDbCriteria / ActiveRecord when combined with Yii Console Commands

Yii version 1.1.13

The below code works when called from a controller. Because the HTTP Session is accessable.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='first_name';
$criteria->condition='id=:contactid';
$criteria->params=array(':contactid'=>4);
$contact=Contact::model()->find($criteria); // <-- exception occurs here... strange
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($contact->first_name);
echo '</pre>';
```

However, when accessing via Yii Console Command I receive the following error and top 2 strack trace lines:

```
    exception 'CException' with message 'CConsoleApplication and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getSessiorks/yii/1.1.13/base/CComponent.php:265
Stack trace:
#0 /home/stm/stm_frameworks/yii/1.1.13/web/auth/CWebUser.php(193): CComponent->__call('getSession', Array)
#1 /home/stm/stm_frameworks/yii/1.1.13/web/auth/CWebUser.php(193): CConsoleApplication->getSession()
```

I can understand that the session is not available to console commands, but why is it even accessing the session? I'm not great with Yii framework. Is [class]::mode()->find($criteria) how I should be inflating a object using ActiveRecord? Seems to match the examples I've found online

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is an example of the command class

```
<?php

class FlahCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    var $id;

    public function actionIndex() {
        return 0; // not implemented
    }

    public function actionBlah($contactId=0) {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select='first_name';
        $criteria->condition='id=:contactid';
        $criteria->params=array(':contactid'=>$contactId);
        $contact=Contact::model()->find($criteria); // <-- exception occurs here... strange
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($contact->first_name);
        echo '</pre>';

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code you've got into your consoleCommand class?

Comment: I didn't list any code, i just listed a snippet I know it crashes on the $contact=Contact::model()->find($criteria); line

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I've ammended the question with example command class.

Comment: It's quite weird. Have you set any `CWebUser` configurations in your `console.php` config file? or does your `Contact` model has any attached `behavior` interacting with `CWebUser` ?

Comment: I'll have a check, as I mentioned though I'm not proficient with Yii, i have more experience with zend, code igniter and Laravel. but I'll see what I can find

Comment: @wired00 you should also check your the `defaultScope` or `beforeFind` for your `Contact` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up figuring out that the client was including a model which i'd missed. Its solved now thanks for the insight people gave

Answer (score 1):

When working with the yii console feature, be aware of the `console.php` wich is the config  file for console applications just as `main.php` stores params and options for yii web applications. So , when you create an app in `yii 1.1.13` by default it does not have the import param inside the `console.php`, this param is responsible for handling part of yii autoloading so you will be missing classes, what i did was to add the following in my `console.php` as a new element of the array inside the file

```
'import'=>array(
            'application.models.*',
            'application.components.*',
            'application.behaviors.*',
            'application.modules.content.*',
            'application.modules.content.models.*',
            'application.extensions.*',
    ),
```

hope this solves your problem, be also aware that although this is autoloading several classes you might not need all of them, using name of specific namesfiles instead of `*` wildcard could be best practice.